# Have default s3.amazonaws.com to be on other region than us-east-1

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So I am trying to debug something, I am not going to explain the problem as it would be too complex, but I would to confirm a part of AWS feature.

If I am in a region, let say us-west-1, an EC2 make a call to  `https://<mybucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/`.
So the default url (usually made for us-east-1), not specifying endpoint.
Thanks to the routing, ca we redirect the url to be in the region of ca-central?

Comment: No idea what you want. Not your job to redirect S3 traffic. From where are you making a request to what URL, where is the S3 bucket hosted primarily, what is the expected outcome and why?

Comment: I have no control over the url, only the bucket. Yet I see the request made to https://<mybucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/ sent to us-west. I am trying to figure out how this done.

Comment: I repeat verbatim: from where are you making a request to what URL, where is the S3 bucket hosted primarily, what is the expected outcome and why?

Comment: I make a request from us-west to  https://<mybucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/.
It ends up to a bucket located in us-west

Comment: And what is confusing about that? What else do you expect and why? I simply do not understand what the issue is, have no idea.

Comment: Because https://<mybucket>.s3.amazonaws.com usually direct you by default to us-east-1, not the local region.
So I was wondering if some configuration make that hitting https://<mybucket>.s3.amazonaws.com will redirect you not to us-east-1, but the local region you are.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  A DNS query for <mybucket>.s3.amazonaws.com will return an IP for S3 in the region that <mybucket> is in (or, in the case that <mybucket> doesn't exist, it will return an IP for S3 in us-east-1)

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. 
However not sure how it works. If I make a request it will still goes out of VPC and back to us-east S3. And if I try to add a VPC endpoint I can only do it to ca-central, not the default s3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to modify the behaviour of the `https://<mybucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/` URL.

However, Amazon S3 will lookup the location of the bucket and will forward the request to the region where the bucket resides.